# Peewee .first() modifies in-memory lists

Tags: orm, peewee

I use Peewee as my ORM and while trying to use `.first()` to get the first element in a list of objects, I found this weird behaviour, where the in-memory list of objects gets modified.

```
In [7]: events = Event.select()

In [8]: len(events)
Out[8]: 10000 # correct count of events in my local DB

In [9]: first_event = events.first()

In [10]: first_event
Out[10]: <Event: 311718318>

In [11]: len(events)
Out[11]: 1 # the in-memory list of events has somehow been changed
```

I initially had 10k objects of `Event`, and just by doing `.first()`, that in-memory list `events` gets modified somehow. This seems very weird and I faced a lot of customer issues on production because of this. Thus, I wanted to know if this is some known issue with Peewee, or maybe my understanding isn't right.

Going through my previous experience with Django, `.first()` simply returns the first element in the list or `None`, and doesn't do anything to the in-memory list of objects. Why is the behaviour different in Peewee? I couldn't find anything relevant in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Peewee `.first()` explicitly appends a `LIMIT 1` so that multiple invocations of `.first()` do not result in multiple queries being executed when you only want the first result. This behavior is a bit different than `.get()`, which will execute a fresh query every time you call it.

You can explicitly clone your query before calling `.first()` if this behavior is undesirable:

```
events = Event.select()
first = events.clone().first()
```

Alternatively, I'd suggest using `.get()` and catching the `Event.DoesNotExist` *or* using plain-old `first_event = events[0]` and catching the possible `IndexError`.